# Wget with input-file and output-document

Tags: bash, wget, xargs

I have a list of URLs which I would like to feed into wget using --input-file.

However I can't work out how to control the --output-document value at the same time,
which is simple if you issue the commands one by one.
I would like to save each document as the MD5 of its URL.

```
 cat url-list.txt | xargs -P 4 wget
```

And xargs is there because I also want to make use of the max-procs features for parallel downloads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about using a loop?

```
while read -r line
do
   md5=$(echo "$line"|md5sum)
   wget ... $line ... --output-document $md5 ......
done < url-list.txt
```

Comment: I think my problem was only having discovered xargs today, I didn't get it, but your answer gave me the clue to have xargs call a bash script with all the wget logic.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `cat`. You can have `xargs` read from a file. From the `man` page:

```
       --arg-file=file
       -a file
              Read items from file instead of standard input.  If you use this
              option, stdin remains unchanged when commands are  run.   Other‐
              wise, stdin is redirected from /dev/null.
```

Comment: @btk: `xargs -P 4 -a url-list.txt wget`

Answer (score 2):

In your question you use -P 4 which suggests you want your solution to run in parallel. GNU Parallel http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/ may help you:

```
cat url-list.txt | parallel 'wget {} --output-document "`echo {}|md5sum`"'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that like this :

> cat url-list.txt | while read url;
>   do
>     wget $url -O $( echo "$url" | md5 );
>   done

good luck